# When does Ontario's HST come into effect?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, gst, sales-tax

When does the HST become effective? Will all businesses start charging HST right away, and will it replace the 5% GST with a straight 13% tax for all services?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the HST will be in effect in Ontario on **July 1st, 2010**.

As to whether it will replace GST with HST for all services, it looks like some sectors *may* get special treatment: [Ontario may exempt mutual funds from HST (National Post)](http://www.financialpost.com/story.html?id=2051364).  But it doesn't look final yet.

However, I would suggest that *most* service-based businesses in Ontario need to prepare to start charging 13% HST instead of 5% GST.  It will be the law.

On the "goods" side of the new harmonized tax, it looks like certain goods will still be exempt from the provincial portion.  Here's a quote from the [Ontario Budget 2009 News Release](http://www.fin.gov.on.ca/en/budget/ontariobudgets/2009/nr.html):

> "Books, diapers, children's clothing
>   and footwear, children's car seats and
>   car booster seats, and feminine
>   hygiene products would be exempt from
>   the provincial portion of the single
>   sales tax."

Here's some additional information on the introduction of the HST, from the province:
[General Transitional Rules for Ontario HST](http://news.ontario.ca/rev/en/2009/10/general-transitional-rules-for-ontario-hst.html).

And finally, another interesting article from the Ottawa Business Journal: [Preparing For Ontario Sales Tax Harmonization – It's Not Too Early](http://www.ottawabusinessjournal.com/299001741870601.php)

---

**UPDATE:**

I just received an insert from Canada Revenue Agency included with my quarterly GST statement.  Titled "Harmonization of the Sales Tax in Ontario and British Columbia", it contains a section titled "What this means for you" (as in, you the business owner).  Here's an excerpt:

> [...]
>
> - All Ontario and B.C. registrants would need to update their accounting
>     and point-of-sale systems to
>     accomodate the change in rate and new
>     point-of-sale rebates for the
>     implementation date of July 1, 2010.
> - The harmonization of the sales tax in Ontario and B.C. may affect the
>     filing requirements of registrants
>     outside of these two provinces.
> - Registrants will report their HST according to their current GST filing
>     frequency.
> - As a result of the harmonization, there will be changes to the rebates
>     for housing and public service bodies.
>
> More information will be released as
>   it becomes available. Visit the CRA
>   web site often, at
>   [www.cra.gc.ca/harmonization](http://www.cra.gc.ca/harmonization), for
>   the most up-to-date information on the
>   harmonization of the sales tax and how
>   it may affect you. [...]

Last, I found some **very detailed** information on the HST here: [NOTICE247 - Harmonized Sales Tax for Ontario and British Columbia - Questions and Answers on General Transitional Rules for Personal Property and Services](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/gi/notice247/).  Chances are anything you want to know is in there.

Comment: As to the question "Why do we even have HST?": In a nutshell: The Ontario provincial government requires more tax revenue to prevent deeper deficits, and HST is one of the ways to increase tax revenues while - in theory - also simplifying the tax system by eliminating PST/RST. HST is a controversial change, that's for sure.

Answer (score 3):

In general you must charge HST on and after **July 1, 2010**.

However, in the case of delivered sales, you must charge HST *if the transfer of goods will happen on or after July 1,2010*.

Example:

> A person comes into my hypothetical store on June 29, 2010 and buys a couch.  They opt to have it delivered by my truck on July 2, 2010.  I should charge HST on this purchase, not GST/PST.

---

**References:**

- [General Transitional Rules for Ontario HST](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/notices/hst/03.html) (Department of Revenue)
- [Are you HST-ready?](http://www.cfib-fcei.ca/cfib-documents/DIN0739.pdf) (CFIB)

Answer (score 2):

### More questions related to the introduction of HST in Ontario:

*(community wiki)*

- [Ontario special HST sales tax transition rebate cheques: When and how much?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/ontario-special-hst-sales-tax-transition-rebate-cheques-when-and-how-much)
- [What will happen to quarterly GST cheques when HST starts in Ontario?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/811/what-will-happen-to-quarterly-gst-cheques-when-hst-starts-in-ontario)
- [Ontario HST rebate: When would I qualify?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1507/ontario-hst-rebate-when-would-i-qualify)
- [Ontario gas prices & HST: What will happen to prices at the pump on July 1, 2010?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1121/ontario-gas-prices-hst-what-will-happen-to-prices-at-the-pump-on-july-1-2010)
- [How will Ontario’s HST apply to books / textbooks, which were PST exempt before?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1376/how-will-ontarios-hst-apply-to-books-textbooks-which-were-pst-exempt-before)
- [How can I minimize the impact of the HST?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/645/how-can-i-minimize-the-impact-of-the-hst)
- [How does the HST affect a condominium purchase?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1239/how-does-the-hst-affect-a-condominium-purchase)
- [Will I need to pay HST on condo maintenance fees?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1238/will-i-need-to-pay-hst-on-condo-maintenance-fees)
- [My Ontario small business collects only PST (beneath GST threshold). How will HST affect me?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/my-ontario-small-business-collects-only-pst-beneath-gst-threshold-how-will-hst)