# How can I minimize the impact of the HST?

Tags: canada, hst, sales-tax, taxes

HST is being introduced in both Ontario ([see this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/65/when-does-ontarios-hst-come-into-effect)) and B.C.,  does anyone have suggestions for how to reduce its impact on individuals?

Answer (score 3):

The HST is a sales tax levied on most goods and services. It is important to realize that in both BC and Ontario, the new HST does not (in most cases) result in an increase in sales tax paid. For example, in Ontario the PST is 8% and when combined with the GST the sales tax is 13%. With the HST, the GST and PST are replaced by a single HST of 13% so the tax bill does not change.

Some services that were previously not subject to PST (such as mutual fund service fees and labour) will now be subject to the HST. So some things will increase. Over time, this should not have a material impact on the consumer due to the way businesses remit GST/HST.