# What will happen to quarterly GST cheques when HST starts in Ontario?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, gst-credit

The Federal government gives GST cheques to those who have qualifying incomes.  What will happen in Ontario when the taxes merge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing significant will happen.  The program will continue to operate as before.

The **GST/HST Credit program** sends cheques to people with [low and modest incomes](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/gsthst/gstc%5Fncms-eng.html) whether residing in a province with GST (such as Ontario before July 1, 2010) or a province with HST (such as Ontario after July 1, 2010.)

For additional information on the GST/HST Credit program, please consult:

- [GST/HST Credit](http://www.servicecanada.gc.ca/eng/goc/gst%5Fcredit.shtml) at Service Canada.
- [Goods and Services Tax/Harmonized Sales Tax (GST/HST) credit](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/gsthst/menu-eng.html) at Canada Revenue Agency.