# Ontario gas prices & HST: What will happen to prices at the pump on July 1, 2010?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, sales-tax

When the HST comes into effect on July 1, 2010 will gas prices at the pump be affected immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a page, [Canada Gasoline Tax Information - Ontario Gas Prices](http://www.ontariogasprices.com/Can_Tax_Info.aspx), listing fuel taxes by province.  Ontario's gas prices already includes 14.7 cents per litre of provincial fuel tax, and comments noted "Additional taxes include 5% GST."  For Nova Scotia and New Brunswick, where HST is in effect, comments noted "Additional taxes include 13% HST."

That would seem to *imply* that if Ontario is introducing the HST, then there **will** be an additional 8% added (Ontario's current PST) to the price at the pump.  I wanted **definitive** information, though, so I did a little more digging:

First, I came across [Gasoline Tax in Ontario](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/BULLETINS/gt/gas1_2003.html#Tax), at the Ontario Ministry of Revenue, confirming fuel tax of "14.7 cents per litre of unleaded gasoline".  While it confirmed the fuel tax, it didn't mention GST or HST.

Next I found [How are consumers affected by the HST?](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/taxchange/changetaxstatus.html), also from the Ontario MoR.  That page lists goods & services that *won't* be affected because they are already subject to both GST + PST, and then goes on to list those that ***will*** be affected since they aren't currently subject to PST.  One item listed under "Change in Taxable Status" is **gasoline**:

> ...
>   *some goods and services that were not subject to the PST will be subject
>   to the provincial portion (eight per cent) of the HST for the first time.* ...
>
> **Change in Taxable Status**
>
> - Electricity
> - **Gasoline**
> - Heating Fuels
> - Internet Access Fees
> - Personal Services (e.g., Hairstyling)
> - Professional Services (e.g., Legal, Accounting and Real Estate Fees
>     and Commissions)
> - Tobacco

So: **I expect all-in fuel prices in Ontario to jump on July 1st, 2010, when HST takes effect.**

Finally, here's one more resource I came across:  Petro Canada has a blog called [PumpTalk](http://www.pumptalk.ca) with this post: [HST & Gasoline. A look at where it's already in place](http://www.pumptalk.ca/2009/03/hst-fuel-whats-happened-in-other-provinces.html) (March, 2009).  Relevant excerpt:

> ... Obviously there are many details
>   yet to be released, so this is just
>   for fun.  If nothing were to change,
>   simply adding the 8% Ontario PST and
>   applying it the same way as the GST is
>   applied to today's pump price in
>   Ontario would add 6.6 cents in tax to
>   a litre of gasoline.  That means a
>   pump price of about 92 cents per litre
>   today in Toronto rather than 86
>   cents...or about $2.64 more for that
>   40 litre fill-up.    ...

Comment: Chris - thanks for the response!  I almost wonder when I am I going get my GM car since it seems this tax is mainly covering the bailout of that company.

Answer (score 1):

Oil companies always up their prices to piggy-back on tax increases.  Expect an $0.08-$0.10 per litre increase.