# My Ontario small business collects only PST (beneath GST threshold). How will HST affect me?

Tags: canada, ontario, gst, hst, small-business

I own a small business in Ontario

and make less than $30,000 per year.

I only charge the PST

Will I be affected by the new HST

and if so, how ?

====================

Also:

If the PST is going to be scrapped, and say I am not affected by HST

how will I pay the pst I've collected from my customers ?

Will it have a new name or will it be the same as it is now ?

Answer (score 1):

I've looked into this and found the following information at the Ontario Ministry of Revenue, at the page [Are You HST Ready?](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/taxchange/transition.html):

> **Will I have to register to collect the
>   HST?**
>
> Businesses that are registered for GST
>   will be required to collect the HST.
>
> *To reduce the administrative burden
>   for small businesses, **Ontario will
>   parallel the federal small supplier
>   threshold. In general, businesses with
>   sales under the threshold (those with
>   total taxable sales of $30,000 or less
>   in the last year or $50,000 or less in
>   the case of a public service body)
>   will not be required to register and
>   collect tax.*** [emphasis mine]
>
> Small suppliers that choose not to
>   register will not be required to file
>   a tax return and will not be eligible
>   to claim input tax credits. If a small
>   supplier chooses to register, it will
>   be eligible to claim input tax credits
>   related to its taxable supplies when
>   it files its tax return.

Note: Your final payment of Ontario Retail Sales Tax (RST, a.k.a. PST) would be due **July 23rd, 2010.**

Then, considering your taxable sales are under $30,000 per year, it would be **optional** for you to register for HST.  However, there may be a benefit to registering since you'd be able to claim input tax credits – that may work out in your favor.