# Ontario harmonized sales tax (HST) transition benefit rebate cheques / OSTTB: Who, when, how much?

Tags: canada, hst, ontario, rebate, gst

As part of [introducing the HST this July 1st, 2010](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/65/when-does-ontarios-hst-come-into-effect), the government of Ontario promised to issue special HST rebates to people meeting certain criteria, in order to ease the transition to the new tax.

- Who will receive the special HST rebates?
- How much are the special HST rebates worth?
- When will the special HST rebate cheques be mailed?
- Should those entitled do anything to ensure they receive their rebates?
- In the case of a couple, who are the rebate cheques made payable to?

### ANSWERS ARE BELOW.

**Got a follow-up question?  First, [browse more HST-related questions by clicking here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hst).

If after browsing you find your question wasn't asked already, click "Ask Question" at the top of the page.  Thanks!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the information I was looking for at the **Ontario Ministry of Finance.** Refer to [table 2 in the Ontario Budget 2009: Chapter III: Reforming Ontario's Tax and Pension Systems](http://www.fin.gov.on.ca/en/budget/ontariobudgets/2009/chpt3.html#table2).  Here's an excerpt with my emphasis added:

> [image: Table 2 - Ontario Sales Tax Transition Benefit]
>
> **Benefits would be delivered to
>   eligible Ontario tax filers aged 18
>   and over in each of June 2010,
>   December 2010 and June 2011, totalling
>   a maximum of $300 for single people
>   and $1,000 for single parents and
>   couples.** Each maximum benefit would be
>   reduced by five per cent of the
>   recipients’ previous year’s adjusted
>   family net income over $80,000 for
>   single individuals and over $160,000
>   for families. **To qualify for the two
>   benefits in 2010, a 2009 tax return
>   would have to be filed, and a 2010 tax
>   return would have to be filed for the
>   June 2011 benefit.** About 6.5 million
>   individuals and families in Ontario
>   would receive sales tax transition
>   benefits.
>
> A single person with no children and
>   income of up to $80,000 would receive
>   a benefit of $100 in each of June
>   2010, December 2010 and June 2011. The
>   maximum benefit would be reduced by
>   five per cent of income over $80,000,
>   so a single person with income of
>   $81,000, for example, would receive
>   three benefits of $50 each. Single
>   people with income over $82,000 would
>   not receive a benefit.
>
> A family with income of up to $160,000
>   would receive three benefits: $330 in
>   June 2010, $335 in December 2010 and
>   $335 in June 2011. The maximum
>   benefits would be reduced by five per
>   cent of family income over $160,000,
>   so a family with income of $163,000,
>   for example, would receive one benefit
>   payment of $180 and two benefit
>   payments of $185 each. Families with
>   income over $166,700 ($166,600 for the
>   June 2010 benefit) would not receive a
>   benefit.
>   ...

On the last point now in the question, regarding who gets the rebates in the case of a couple, I found the answer at the Ontario Ministry of Revenue (second link below):

> To qualify for the OSTTB, you are required to file a 2009 income tax return for the June
>   2010 and December 2010 payments, and a 2010 return for the June 2011 payment. If both
>   you and your spouse or common-law partner file a tax return, **the benefit payments will
>   be made to the individual whose return is assessed by the CRA first.**

Information at the Ontario Ministry of Revenue:

- [Tax Benefits for Families](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/taxchange/families.html#transitionpay), and
- **[Ontario Sales Tax Transition Benefit](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/index.html)  ←** *good definitive information here!*

Here's some of the basic eligibility information from the second link (OSTTB) just above:

> For the June 2010 benefit payment you
>   must:
>
> - be a resident of Canada on
>     December 31, 2009 and file a 2009
>     income tax return by April 30, 2011;
>     or if you were not a resident of
>     Canada on December 31, 2009, provide a
>     statement of 2009 world income to CRA,
>     by April 30, 2011
> - be 18 years of age or older or
>     have a spouse or common-law partner or
>     live with your dependant child on May
>     31, 2010
> - be a resident of Ontario on May
>     31, 2010.
>
> ... etc ...

#### So, *file your income tax return* to make sure you're in the system for the OSTTB rebates!

If you haven't filed your income tax return for 2009 yet, you can download the Ontario income tax forms package at [Canada Revenue Agency - Ontario - 2009 General Income Tax and Benefit package.](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/formspubs/t1gnrl/on-eng.html).

Canada Revenue Agency also has a good list of **[Ontario Sales Tax Transition Benefit Questions and Answers](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/rltd_prgrms/fq_sttb-eng.html)** available.  Check it out!

**Got a follow-up question?  First, [browse more HST-related questions by clicking here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=hst&sort=active&pagesize=50).

If your question wasn't asked already, click "Ask Question" at the top of the page.  Thanks!**

Answer (score 4):

I called the GST helpline...according to the message, The June 2010 payment will be released "in mid-June". I also read online on the goftp website that the release date is June 10th (for direct deposit..that is the day it goes into my account). For mail out dates, wait 3-5 days mailing time.

Answer (score 4):

Will the OSTTB  affect Employment Insurance, Social Assistance or income-tested benefits?

The OSTTB will not have any impact on Employment Insurance, Social Assistance or income-tested benefits.

as per
http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_general.html#Q23

Hope that helps

Answer (score 3):

This is the link for the info on when payments will be made. The first payment being **June 10, 2010**.    http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/taxchange/families.html

Answer (score 2):

I read that the date is June 10th.

Answer (score 1):

My co-worker filed her taxes and got direct deposit, and got her HST rebate in her bank this morning...  I on the other hand, get cash back for my taxes, but I do get my Child Tax Credit direct deposited... but I did not get a HST deposit... It must be comming by cheque for me.