# Are the HST rebates only paid for the first year, or will they be issued every year?

Tags: canada, hst, gst, rebate, tax-credit

Will the HST rebates be paid each year after 2010 as well, or is this a one time thing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're referring to the provincial **[Ontario Sales Tax Transition Benefit](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/index.html)**, it is designed to be **temporary only**, and is directly related to the introduction of the HST in Ontario this July 1st, 2010.  Refer:

> As part of Ontario's new comprehensive
>   tax package, the Ontario Sales Tax
>   Transition Benefit (OSTTB) will
>   provide temporary relief to residents
>   of Ontario to help them adjust to the
>   new harmonized sales tax system that
>   comes into effect on July 1, 2010.

The transition cheques issued under the OSTTB are to be issued in: **June 2010**, **December 2010**, and **June 2011**.  That's it.  Those cheques will **not** be issued every year. See also the question [Ontario special HST sales tax transition rebate cheques: When and how much?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/ontario-special-hst-sales-tax-transition-rebate-cheques-when-and-how-much)

---

If you're referring to, on the other hand, the benefit cheques that some people receive as a result of the **[GST/HST Credit](http://www.servicecanada.gc.ca/eng/goc/gst_credit.shtml)** (at the federal level), that program is designed to be ongoing.  Here's a bit of information (or check the previous link):

> The GST/HST Credit program issues
>   payments to Canadians with low and
>   modest incomes to help offset all or
>   part of the GST/HST they pay on the
>   purchase of goods and services.  [...]
>
> To receive the GST/HST credit, the
>   recipient has to apply for it, even if
>   it was received in the previous year.
>   To apply, the recipient must file an
>   Income Tax and Benefit return, even if
>   there is no income to report. Eligible
>   taxpayers may apply for the credits
>   any time during the year in which they
>   meet the requirements.  [...]
>
> The GST/HST credit is issued four times a year:
>   January, April, July and October
>   (generally the fifth day of the month)  [...]