# Ontario HST rebate: Is there such a thing as $500 HST transition cheques, or is it $335?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

Some friends have mentioned getting a $500 government rebate mailed to them... Is it possible that an amount of $500 be payable for the HST transition, or could this be for something else?  It seems to be a max of $335 from the information I've read so far?

Thks

Comment: Thanks Chris,
     I found out the $500 rebate was a Senior Home Property Tax Credit that is being mailed out to those that applied...the grant is mailed 4 to 8 weeks after Notice of Assessment received. 
Thanks very much

Answer (score 1):

It must be for something else.  There are a variety of rebates from both the federal and provincial governments.

For instance, one rebate that I found that was exactly $500 was for installing a solar hot water heater.  There may be many other examples.

Rebates from governments come and go as they want to either incentivize citizens to do something, or compensate them in the short term to make a tax hike more palatable (such as with the HST.)

In any case, the HST transition cheques for a family are: three separate amounts paid over one year: $330, $335, then $335 again, as described at [this other question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/ontario-special-hst-sales-tax-transition-rebate-cheques-when-and-how-much).  There is no $500 transition rebate amount.