# Ontario HST rebate: I am now 18. Do I get the last rebate cheque?

Tags: canada, hst, ontario, rebate

I turned 18 in September 2010. I filed my income tax for 2010. Will I receive an HST rebate cheque for June 2011?  How much could I expect?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since you filed your 2010 income tax return *and* were 18 or older on **May 31, 2011** (the qualification date for the final cheque), then you should receive a rebate cheque for $100.

**Note that you would have also qualified for the December 2010 cheque** since you were also 18 on November 30, 2010 (the qualification date for the second cheque), but unfortunately, you would have needed to filed your 2009 taxes by April 30th, 2011.

Answer (score 0):

See This Answer [Ontario harmonized sales tax (HST) transition benefit rebate cheques](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1224/ontario-harmonized-sales-tax-hst-transition-benefit-rebate-cheques-osttb-who) which should help you.