# Will I need to pay HST on condo maintenance fees?

Tags: canada, hst

Are condo fees going to go up when the HST goes into effect? If so, are there any exemptions to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as per the Ontario FAQ on the HST.

[FAQ Question 33 "The HST will not apply to condominium maintenance fees"](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/taxchange/faq.html#q33)

It does note that some of the services that condo buildings purchase will be subject to HST, so the condo fee itself might have to change, but therefore indirectly, as opposed to being subject to the tax itself.