# How does Ontario's new HST affect a condominium purchase?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, real-estate

I'm wondering what the rules are regarding HST and a purchase of a condominium.

1. When buying a new construction condominium, would I need to pay HST?
2. What about for existing (re-sale) condo's?

I've heard new constructions below a certain value are exempt from HST... but its conflicting information so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 2 first: resale is exempt [31. Will there be HST on the purchase of new homes and resale homes?](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/taxchange/faq.html#q31)

The new homes is a little messier [Rebate Description](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/taxchange/homebuyers.html) goes into some detail.  Effectively if the home is $400,000 or less, then a government rebate should offset the HST, to effectively be back to where you would have been with the old RST (Retail Sales Tax).

Excruciating details are [Here](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/notices/hst/02.html)