# How will Ontario's HST apply to books / textbooks, which were PST exempt before?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, education

Students (university/college) have been hit hard enough recently with tuition hikes.  How will this latest cost increase affect the cost of education materials?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Books stay exempt, see this [No Change](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/taxchange/changetaxstatus.html) list.

*Basic* groceries also stay exempt; so your Kraft Dinner will remain the same price also.  :-)