# Ontario HST rebate: When would I qualify?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate, sales-tax

I turned 18 in January 2010 and I filed a 2009 income tax return. When will I qualify to receive the rebate?

Answer (score 3):

If you filed your 2009 tax return and are eligible, you will receive your first rebate cheque this year. It is paid out 4 times a year, starting this August, and is a maximum of $260. Remember that you will also receive your first transition cheque in June for $100 and then another in December and next June - $300 in total.